# Azure Files performance for a remote IPSEC VPN connected site

Tags: azure, server-message-block, smbclient

I have an Azure Files premium account which I setup SMB multichannel.  I setup a test folder with 50,000 very small files.

If I test with a single file at a remote IPSEC connected site I get around 5-10 MB/s.  For a 5TB azure files premium this seems very slow.

I have a standard VM that is able to transfer a single large file at 60 MB/s without issue.  1.)  Is Azure files really that much slower for SMB on a windows 10 machine with 30 ms latency?

2.)  Azure files multi-channel seems to not make a difference on a windows 10 machine with a single NIC.  The file copy in windows explorer is still single threaded when copying and therefore I am only getting file copy speeds of 500 KB to 2MB/s when there are 10,000 - 50,000 files.  The smaller the files of course less bandwidth since we are talking about a single threaded operation.  Any way to get SMB 3.1.1 with AES-128-GMAC to perform faster?

Comment: What kind of OS is the VM and which version?

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a feature in Preview called metadata caching which might improve performance
Metadata caching is an enhancement for SMB Azure premium file shares aimed to reduce metadata latency, increase available IOPS, and boost network throughput. This preview feature improves the following metadata APIs and can be used from both Windows and Linux clients.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/smb-performance#metadata-caching-for-premium-smb-file-shares